# How to set the kafka message key in the ProducerRecord

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Currently I am using org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate to publish avro messages on the topic with headers.

```
@Override
public ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> send(Message<?> message) {
    ProducerRecord<?, ?> producerRecord = this.messageConverter.fromMessage(message, this.defaultTopic);
    if (!producerRecord.headers().iterator().hasNext()) { // possibly no Jackson
        byte[] correlationId = message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, byte[].class);
        if (correlationId != null) {
            producerRecord.headers().add(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, correlationId);
        }
    }
    return doSend((ProducerRecord<K, V>) producerRecord);
}
```

In the Message<?>, we can set the value and headers but can't set the key. Is there a way to have key in the header? If so could you please let me know the header name for the key? Is there a way to send key, value and header using KafkaTemplate

Comment: `messageConverter.fromMessage` doesn't already set the ProducerRecord key? What type of object is `this.messageConverter`?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the headers on the `ProducerRecord`, e.g.:

```
RecordHeader yourHeader = new RecordHeader("yourHeaderName", "yourValue".toByteArray())
record.headers().add(recordHeaderKafkaMessageKey)
```

**Edit**: misread the requirements, sorry. There is a defined kafka header for the message key which is `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY`.

Comment: Actually I need to populate the message key along with header plus the value. I know I can set header but sending header is not an issue. I am not able to send the message key with Message<?>

Comment: Sorry, should have read your question carefully. Does `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY` help?